# Framework to create a JMS receiver

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I want to create a JMS receiver/consumer in Java and this is first time for me to use JMS. I wanted to look some examples and frameworks which I can use but got little confused. Could you please tell me if the following frameworks serve the same purpose?

```
Spring JMS
ActiveMQ
Spring JMS with ActiveMQ
RabbitMQ
```

Also, are there any other good frameworks? 
Which one is easy to learn and which is better in performance?
What is Spring JMS with ActiveMQ?

In general, I am a big fan of spring...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring JMS is the Spring abstraction over the JMS API.

JMS is just an API; you need a physical broker to actually do messaging.

ActiveMQ is not a framework, it is an open-source JMS broker that supports the actual persistence and delivery of messages.

Spring JMS can be used with any JMS broker, including ActiveMQ. Each broker provides its own JMS API client jar.

RabbitMQ is not a native JMS broker; its native protocol is AMQP 0.9.1; it does, however, provide a JMS API client that can be used with Spring JMS, but Spring AMQP is the preferred library for talking to RabbitMQ because it provides much more functionality than is available over JMS.

There are lots of examples for using Spring JMS on the internet.

The simplest way to get started is with Spring Boot and `@JmsListener`.

If you have specific questions, you should start new ones rather than using comments on this one.

Comment: Do I need a broker just for consuming the messages also?

Comment: The broker is the actual place where messages are stored; a producer sends messages to the broker and the broker routes them to consumer(s); either point-to-point (queue) or publish/subscribe (topic) - where each consumer gets a copy. A broker is required; ActiveMQ provides an in-memory embedded broker which can be useful for integration tests; but you generally need a stand-alone persistent broker for a production application.